# Problems to compare two strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, csv

I created a code in PHP. This code basically take to files .csv and comparer the strings inside in this files.
Here is my code:
index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Triangulação</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="csv1" value="" />
        <br>
        <input type="file" name="csv2" value="" />
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Upload:

```
<?php
    $csv = array();
    // check there are no errors
    if($_FILES['csv1']['error'] == 0 && $_FILES['csv2']['error'] == 0){
        $name1 = $_FILES['csv1']['name'];
        $name2 = $_FILES['csv2']['name'];
        $ext1 = strtolower(explode('.', $_FILES['csv1']['name'])[1]);
        $ext2 = strtolower(explode('.', $_FILES['csv2']['name'])[1]);
        $type1 = $_FILES['csv1']['type'];
        $type2 = $_FILES['csv2']['type'];
        $tmpName1 = $_FILES['csv1']['tmp_name'];
        $tmpName2 = $_FILES['csv2']['tmp_name'];

        // check the file is a csv
        if($ext1 == 'csv' && $ext2 == 'csv'){
            if(($handle1 = fopen($tmpName1, 'r')) != FALSE) {
                // necessary if a large csv file
                set_time_limit(0);

                $row = 0;

                while(($data1 = fgetcsv($handle1, 1024, ',')) != FALSE) {
                    // number of fields in the csv
                    if(($handle2 = fopen($tmpName2, 'r')) != FALSE){
                        set_time_limit(0);
                        $dna1 = $data1[1];
                        while(($data2 = fgetcsv($handle2, 1024, ',')) != FALSE) {
                            $dna2 = $data2[1];
                            if(strcmp($dna1, $dna2) == 0){
                                printf("<p> %s </p>", $dna1);
                            }
                        }
                        fclose($handle2);
                    }
                }
                fclose($handle1);
            }
        }
    }
    
?>
```

Something is wrong in this part: if(strcmp($dna1, $dna2) == 0).
I do not know why this code has a error:

[image]

Here is the files csv that i used:

file1: https://github.com/rrodrigofranco/fornoPID/blob/main/B802828_Family_Finder_Matches_2021-10-02.csv

file2: https://github.com/rrodrigofranco/fornoPID/blob/main/B802890_Family_Finder_Matches_2021-10-02.csv
Someone can help me?

Comment: What do you mean by `Something is wrong in this part: if(strcmp($dna1, $dna2) == 0).`. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: You need to give us much more to go on here. We have no idea what your files contains or what you're actually comparing so it's pretty hard to know where or why it fails.

Comment: I update the question, I added a picture showing the error and the files that I used

Comment: Show the file in a way we do not have to risk visiting a unknown site.

Comment: I puted the files on the github. It is more ease to see and take the files

Comment: If your purpose is just to compare the two files, why do you use nested while loops ?

Comment: I want to compare only the names of the two files, I am using while loopes, because I am comparing the names one by one. Do you have better Idea?

Comment: The error is referring to this line, `$dna2 = $data2[1];` - meaning, `$data2` was not an array containing at least two elements at this point. Interesting question would be, do you get these errors on the first iteration of the inner while loop already - or maybe only from the second one on? In general, it doesn't make too much sense to read through that second file over and over again, I would much rather read the data into an array first, and then loop over that multiple times.

Comment: So... This problems appear always with the huge csv document, when I put a short csv file, the program working perfectly